# How to add nofollow to drop down

Tags: select, indexing, drop-down-menu, nofollow

I have a drop down list which filters category ASC and DESC. Google doesn't seem to understand that is duplicate content. How can I prevent Google from not following the drop down selections:

```
<select>
        <select class="sort-by-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" name="ssort">
        <option onclick="window.location = "http://mysite.com/category1/sort/_post_name-pp-asc/"; return false;" selected="" value="http://mysite.com/category1/sort/_post_name-pp-asc/">Name ASC</option>
        <option onclick="window.location = "http://mysite.com/category1/sort/_post_name-pp-desc/"; return false;" value="http://mysite.com/category1/sort/_post_name-pp-desc/">Name DESC</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure `rel="nofollow"` only works within `<a>` tags.

Don't think it will work with a window.location

Comment: so are there any other alternatives in such cases?